# Why is R Markdown giving me a LaTeX error when trying to knit to pdf?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to knit a PDF document using R Markdown. The markdown successfully knits to 100% but upon trying to create the output file, it produces the following error:

```sh
output file: project_2_cusack.knit.md

/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/pandoc/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS project_2_cusack.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output project_2_cusack.tex --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/latex-div.lua --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
! Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
\end@float ... \@tempdima \penalty \@floatpenalty 
                                                  \else \vadjust {\penalty -...
l.385 \end{figure}

Error: LaTeX failed to compile project_2_cusack.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See project_2_cusack.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I have specified to save as PDF so unsure why it is trying to knit as a tex file.

Any suggestions on troubleshooting?

Comment: You need Latex to knit to pdf. Install tinytext and retry

Comment: I have tinytex installed and updated, which is why I am a bit confused about the error.

Comment: Have you checked project_2_cusack.log?

Comment: check the lines from `360` to `385`